# Different Expected Values using Different Approaches

Tags: probability-theory

My problem question is:

Let $X$ be the number of spades in $7$ cards dealt from a well-shuffled deck of $52$ cards containing $13$ spades. Find $E[X]$

Now, I was thinking of using a hypergeometric distribution. However, after solving it I got my answer as $\frac{13}{4}$. However, the back of the book and this answer ([Confusion about indicators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78078/confusion-about-indicators)) seem to point to the answer being $\frac{7}{4}$. I have rechecked my work many times and there are no errors. Why are these two numbers different?

Comment: Can someone confirm that my answer of $13/4$ is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still get $\frac{7}{4}$ using a hypergeometric distribution:

$$\sum_{k=1}^7 k \left(\matrix{13\\ k}\right)\left(\matrix{52-13\\ 7-k}\right)/ \left(\matrix{52\\ 7}\right) = 7/4.
$$

Comment: Why is it $7-k$ and $\binom{52}{7}$ instead of $13-k$ and $\binom{52}{13}$?

Comment: I used the pmf formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: @user371369 n -k = 7-k because n is the number of draws.